# Why do I get an Import Error( cannot import name) when trying to import the base class in the inherited class?

Tags: python

Hi I am writing a Bowling game with **four classes; each in their own file but all in the same Directory/Folder**; Game(uses all the other classes),Frame(are the turns, uses Roll),**tenth_Frame(inherits from Frame)**, Roll (returns number of Pins). I get the **Import Error cannot Import Name Frame in my tenth_Frame class**.  Also this is my first question here and I hope I included everything needed  : )

I tried to figure it out, read multiple sites/QnA but couldnt find a solution. I tried to  Change the Import but all I manage to get are different error Messages (Frame is not defined)

Game.py

```
from Module_Frame import*
from Roll import*
from tenth_Frame import*
class Game:....
```

Module_Frame.py

```
from Game import*
from Roll import*

class Frame():
    def __init__(self,game):
        self._score=0
        self._moves=Roll()
        self.game=game
        self.make_move()
```

Roll.py

```
import random 
from Module_Frame import*
from Game import *
#from tenth_Frame import*

class Roll:...
```

tenth_Frame.py

```
from Module_Frame import Frame

class tenth_Frame(Module_Frame.Frame):
    def __init__(self,game):

        Frame.__init__(self,game)
        self.__sum=0
        ...
```

I get the following result:
ImportError: cannot Import Name Frame

```
File "j:\Programme\Marius Programmierphase.22.07.19\bowling\Game.py", line 2, in <module>
  from Module_Frame import*
File "j:\Programme\Marius Programmierphase.22.07.19\bowling\Module_Frame.py", line 2, in <module>
  from Game import*
File "j:\Programme\Marius Programmierphase.22.07.19\bowling\Game.py", line 3, in <module>
  from Roll import*
File "j:\Programme\Marius Programmierphase.22.07.19\bowling\Roll.py", line 5, in <module>
  from tenth_Frame import*
File "j:\Programme\Marius Programmierphase.22.07.19\bowling\tenth_Frame.py", line 5, in <module>
  class tenth_Frame(Module_Frame.Frame):

NameError: name 'Module_Frame' is not defined
```

So I also tried **in tenth_Frame** to **Change the Import command to**:

1.)

```
from Module_Frame import Frame

class tenth_Frame(Frame):

ImportError: cannot import name Frame
```

2.)

```
import Module_Frame

class tenth_Frame(Frame):

NameError: name 'Frame' is not defined
```

3.)

```
import Module_Frame

class tenth_Frame(Module_Frame.Frame):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Frame'
```

4.)

```
from Module_Frame import *

class tenth_Frame(Module_Frame.Frame):

NameError: name 'Module_Frame' is not defined
```

I read about dependencies and many other Errors, but I still don't get my error (or can't detect it).

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Your nonstandard naming scheme makes it much harder for us to understand what's happening. If you use *PascalCase* for class names and *lowercase* for module names it's easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: thx for the Input. I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You have circular depencies between all your modules. I think no module can be fully parsed, and the names inside the modules are never declared in their scope.

**EDIT:** When Python enters the first file, it tries to read it. To simplify, you have 2 cases: Python find an *instruction* and executes it (e.g. `print("spam")`), or Python find a *definition* (e.g. `def f():`). A definition means a new name will be created and added to the scope it was found, usually for class and function the module scope. Definitions of a module are available to other modules once the original is fully read.

But when it encounters an import, Python switch to the imported file, because an import means some names necessary to understand the original file will be found in the imported file. When you have circular depencies, the core of the file is never read, you are kept inside an import loop, and the definition of class, function... are never available to the other modules.

First you have to clean dependencies: `Roll` cannot import `Module_Frame` when `Module_Frame` import `Roll`. If the class `Games` is needed by all the other modules, it can not import any of the other modules. But it's hard to propose a file structure without the full knowledge of what you want.

Then using:

```
import Module_Frame
class tenth_Frame(Module_Frame.Frame):
     pass
```

or

```
from Module_Frame import Frame
class tenth_Frame(Frame):
     pass
```

should work.

Comment: Ok then I clearly understood the explanation on  dependencies wrong...thank you so much for the quick reply. Basically I tried to structure everything after a given UML Diagramm. I will try to restructure my code and get rid of the dependencies. However I didn't get the part with a module can't be fully parsed (I don't know what that means but will try to figure it out) and the names inside the modules are never declared in their scope. The names inside my module are my attributes and methods right? What is their scope? Could you please clarify to what refers the their in your sentence?

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining in detail that helped a lot. I am rewriting my code now and as soon as I am done I ll test it : )